# How to show second sum-menu in bootstrap 5.3 and HTML?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I want to create a menu with a submenu in Laravel. I wrote this code but it doesn't display the second sub-menu.

For example, I want to show the submenu of `Another dropdown`. But it did not display.

Look at this picture for example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8dfk.png

**My version of Bootstrap is 5.3.**

[image: dropdown]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="fa">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-T5m5WERuXcjgzF8DAb7tRkByEZQGcpraRTinjpywg37AO96WoYN9+hrhDVoM6CaT" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">خدمات</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
              <li class="dropend">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Web Design</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                  <li class="dropend">
                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Company</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Office</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">School</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropend">
                    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tourism</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hotel</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Restaurant</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tour</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Seo</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Content</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Graphic</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">SMS</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Backup</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Google</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">Application</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I imported this code from here https://www.codehim.com/demo/bootstrap-5-mega-menu-responsive-examples/

Could you please help me with how to achieve it? I've tried to use several bootstrap classes, or even hardcode float left and right. Nothing helped. My code is above:

Comment: i don't know what's wrong with your code. but maybe you are using 5.3.0 version that maybe conflict. here is example what you need. please check and let me know if need anything else. https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/dropdown-multilevel/#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the code to add a class `dropdown-item` to the `a` element and it will work:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  data-bs-auto-close="outside">Web Design</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
    <li class="dropend">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Company</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#">Office</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#">School</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#">Shopping</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropend">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tourism</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-submenu shadow">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hotel</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Restaurant</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Tour</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```